# I get 404 deployment error on vercel when I try to deploy vite mern app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, mern, vercel

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFWe9.png)

this is vite config file

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
// import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default defineConfig({

plugins: [react(),],

server: {
proxy: {
'/api': 'http://localhost:5000',
'/uploads': 'http://localhost:5000',
},
},

});

```
import path from 'path';
```

this is server.js file

```
 import express from 'express';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
    dotenv.config();
    import connectDB from './config/db.js';
    import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js';
    import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
    import orderRoutes from './routes/orderRoutes.js';
    import uploadRoutes from './routes/uploadRoutes.js';
    import { notFound, errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js';
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    connectDB();
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);
    app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
    app.use('/api/orders', orderRoutes);
    app.use('/api/upload', uploadRoutes);
    
    app.get('/api/config/paypal', (req, res) =>
      res.send({ clientId: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID })
    );
    
    
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    
      const __dirname = path.resolve();
    
      app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')));
    
    
    
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/dist')));
    
      app.get('*', (req, res) =>
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'dist', 'index.html'))
      );
    } else {
    
      const __dirname = path.resolve();
    
    
      app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')));
    
      app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('API is running....');
      });
    }
    
    app.use(notFound);
    app.use(errorHandler);
    
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${port}`)
    );
```

There's nothing wrong in build logs on vercel and vite docs are not helping at all.

I have backend and frontend folder for this app and wrote npm script to build from root during deployment..